# Write program using a MIDI device in Java

Tags: java, midi

I would like to create a Java program that does simple things to a MIDI device, in this case the Novation Launchpad MK2. It is a grid of 8x8 buttons that can light up. I don't have any experience with using MIDI in Java, and I don't know where to start.

The basic idea is that I want buttons to light up for example when I press them. This means I want to send note and velocity data to the device, but also that pressing a button on the device should send a command to my program. There is documentation on the device on the website of Novation: https://customer.novationmusic.com/support/product-downloads?product=Launchpad.

Is this idea possible, or would it be harder than I imagine it to be? My experience with Java (or programming as a whole) is fairly limited, but I know a good portion of the basics. Anyone an idea on how to do this, how complicated this is and perhaps someone can give me a basic idea how I should go about doing this?

Comment: There's a few posts on Java & Midi on SO already that may help Try:
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462854/midi-beginner-need-to-play-one-note
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266411/java-midi-how-to-get-notes-from-midi-whilst-its-playing
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937760/java-getting-input-from-midi-keyboard

Comment: This question is too broad for SO. Anyway, look at the examples for recording and sending MIDI messages, and combine them.

Answer (score 1):

Java have API for your needs. Just learn it.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing-MIDI.html